# unable to install the update in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

unable to install the update in sharepoint 2013 after updating sp1 i just want to update it to Microsoft SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB2965266) getting error message as "The expected version of the product was not found on the system is there any solution for this

Comment: This is maybe a question for: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ and not SO...

Comment: This queestion belongs to [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You have some language packs installed and one of the language packs is not on the rereleased SP1 level. The CU contains fixes for all languages. If there is a package in the CU which does not have a proper baseline the CU will not install.

Comment: You are exactly right! After uninstalling language pack I was able to install the CU. Thank You!